# Facebook login on Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

After the user logs in using their facebook credentials, The user is shown an authorization screen with two buttons on the bottom:"Skip" and "Ok". How do I detect that the user clicked on the Skip button?
It seems the session is opened for both actions.

```
 Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        @Override public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)               {
Log.d(TAG,"session is open");
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "session is closed");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session.getState()==SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED
```

this mean user click close or Skip button

if user allowed permissions request by your app before (text description of permission like you're already allowed permissions), Skip and OK button are one

Comment: ok, so if they have pre-authorized, skip and ok button mean the same thing.

Comment: Yes, when you see text about authorized before, 2 buttons is same. Facebook will save permission you allowed of app. If you need test again, go to app settings of your account and delete your app in list (not delete app from developer page), you can try to test your code again